# Selecting an element inside Div for CSS decoration

Tags: css, element

I am looking to give black color to each "a" element inside of the listing class. How can I select the "a" element from the listing class in CSS to achieve this?

```
    <ul class="listing">
       <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Advertising</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Brands</li>
       <li><a href="#">Small Businesses</a></li>  
       <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>  
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

`.listing a { color: #000; }`

Though, if you've defined using pseudo classes elsewhere, you may need:

`.listing a:link, .listing a:visited { color: #000; }`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way:

```
ul.listing li a {
    color: black; /* or #000; */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ul.listing li a {
  color: black;
}
```